# Conidtions for a vector field to be geodesic?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a problem in which I have a vector field $u$ on a smooth manifold and want to find a Riemannian metric for which the vector field is geodesic, i.e.
$$\nabla_u u = \sigma u,$$ and $\sigma$ is some smooth function. As a starting point, I would like to understand if there are some necessary conditions that the vector field has to satisfy for this to be true. That is, what are some properties of $u$ that, if they fail, rule out the possibility of finding a metric such that the above equation holds?

Comment: A geodesic is a parametrized curve, not a vector field, so you should rephrase.

Comment: @TedShifrin each integral curve of such a vector field is a (pre-)geodesic, so this seems like a reasonable enough extension of terminology. Besides, using “geodesic” as an adjective in “the vector field is geodesic” isn’t that uncommon: geodesic triangle, geodesic ball/sphere etc.

Comment: Of course, the vector field must be everywhere non-zero. Locally, at least, the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131003/when-can-the-trajectories-of-a-vector-field-be-realized-as-geodesics) is a start.